# sublime livereload не реагирует на CSS

Tags: плагин, sublime-text, reload

Стоит sublime text 3 с плагином LiveReload. Стоит плагин на FireFox livereload, прекрасно работает если сохраняю например footer.php (движок WordPress). Но если в той же папке сохраняю style.css, то браузер не обновляет страницу. Не могу найти причину. Сайт локальный, livereload включен

Comment: причем именно на файлы css не реагирует. На все .php, в подпапках они или в корне, реагирует нормально, обновляет страницу. Только на .css ноль реакции. Перегружал редактор, не помогло. Может настройка какая есть? Не смог ее нагуглить, отпишите кто в курсе

Comment: поменял .css на .xcss и заработало, почему то не хочет именно .css обновлять, что за приколы такие... отпишите кто знает где копать инфу

Comment: Может это подойдет? - https://habr.com/ru/post/189748/